# main.tex does not recognize changes in JabRef when creating footnotes or bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, jabref

I have linked my main.tex with my bibliography in JabRef using \addbibresource{Bibliography_Geoengineering.bib}

However, if I change entries or bibtex keys in the JabRef file, my main.tex does not recognize it entirely. 
First I had errors because the title of a source contained a symbol that could not be displayed by u8, but after changing the title it still did not work. 
So I changed the bibtexkey both in JabRef as in all my citations in my texmaker files. The result was, that all errors concerning the citations were gone, but the one for the bibliography was still there. I saved, restarted and tried everything else with both JabRef and Texmaker but it did not change. So I added a % in front of \printbibliography to at least be able to continue working. 
When I deleted the % and double checked the spelling of the bibresource later, it suddenly ran through without any problems or errors. 
Now I changed a few other bibtex keys and get the following message in blue: "The following entry could not be found" In my PDF version the bibtex keys are displayed instead of the entry in JabRef.

To me it seems like the connection between Texmaker and JabRef is not entirely working for some reason but it is driving me crazy to not understand how the above mentioned thinks happened or are connected.

Comment: What is this connection between jabref and texmaker? As far as I know there is no connection. It is two separate programmes. Did you remember to manually run bibtex in TeXMaker? (I think it is F11)

Comment: They are two seperate programmes but texmaker gets its information from JabRef right? So I suspect a problem somewhere there... I ran quick build (PdfLaTex + Bib(la)Tex + PdfLaTex + view PDF) but also BibTex on my main.tex and it didnt discover any problems. It still keeps on telling me that I have undefined sources in my document, even though I double checked spelling and everything.

Comment: Jabref manages one or more `.bib` files, those are then used by `bibtex`. There is no interaction between jabref and TeXMaker. It might be an idea if you prepare a so-called minimal example, ie a document that others can copy and run on their own computers without having to add anything. Plus a sample of the data from your `.bib` file. Without seeing any of your code, it is nearly impossible for us to help. So please update your question with a minimal example, and sample bibtex data.

Answer (score 1):

What is this connection between jabref and texmaker? As far as I know there is no connection. It is two separate programmes. Did you remember to manually run bibtex in TeXMaker? (I think it is F11)

Jabref manages one or more `.bib` files, those are then used by `bibtex`. There is no interaction between jabref and TeXMaker. It might be an idea if you prepare a so-called minimal example, ie a document that others can copy and run on their own computers without having to add anything. Plus a sample of the data from your .bib file. Without seeing any of your code, it is nearly impossible for us to help. So please update your question with a minimal example, and sample bibtex data.